# Why i can't connect mqtt broker from python?

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto 1.4.15 broker on my ubuntu 18.04. I can read the queue with mosquitto_sub but i cant read by python script.

https://pastebin.com/syMLNvEj

python mqttConn.py
...

`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:727)`

This is working:

```
mosquitto_sub  --tls-version tlsv1.1 --cafile ca.crt -h 192.168.1.192 -t "#" -p 8883 -d --cert client.crt --key client.key
```

The cert file is fine, if i change them i got Common Name error.

Comment: Do not put code on pastebin. Edit the question to include the code directly and format it properly.

Comment: Also have you actually read the command line options for the `mqttConn.py` script?